# fetch double from mysql with 0.00 precision

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to fetch a double column from mysql database using jdbc. I am getting the error using:

```
rs.getDouble(2);
"java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for number '8,008.00' in column 2"
```

I have tried this using :

```
select amount from table;

select format(amount,2) from table;
```

both of the above query are showing bad format...

Comment: Format error makes me think you are storing the number as string (which you shouldn't). How is `amount` defined on db?

Comment: i have used:
create table myTable (customerId id int(11), amount double(5,2));

Comment: i have used it but still problem is same

Comment: `format(amount,2)` Returns a formated string not a number. Which error you get if you use the first Statement?

Comment: @Antoniossss op stores the ist as number: amount double(5,2). the string Comes from the Format function

Comment: @YameenRabbani Also how you can store 8008.00 in a double (5,2)? 5 ist the number of digits

Comment: @YameenRabbani You should Format the amount in your Java code not in the select statement

Comment: Select value not formatted form.

Comment: What is the original type and value of `amount`. The main problem is that a string with value `8,000.00` can't be properly converted to a double because of that thousand separator. And btw, doubles don't have a precision of two decimals. If you want that, you should use a fixed point type like `decimal` or `numeric`.

Comment: Actually I have 123.45 as double data type in mysql ... and I have to fetch it as it is.....